# Find all nodes with an attribute value matching another

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a pmd.xml file looking something like this:

```
<file name="file1">
  <violation rule="rulename1" priority="1">
  </violation>
  <violation rule="rulename2" priority="2">
  </violation>
</file>
<file name="file2">
  <violation rule="rulename2" priority="2">
  </violation>
  <violation rule="rulename3" priority="1">
  </violation>
</file>
```

I'm using a xslt file to transform this in another xml file.

What I now try to do is this:
for each Violation with Priority=1 count the number of violations with the same name in the whole xml. The same later with Prio=2.

So that i can list all the Violations together with the count how often they appear in the document, roughly something like this:

```
prio1:
rulename1, 1
rulename3, 1
prio2:
rulename2, 2
```

I can't find a proper XPath expression to count the violations with the same name...

```
<xsl:for-each select="//violation[@priority = 1]">
<xsl:value-of select="count(???)"/>
```

Anyone got a helping idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you running XSLT 1.0 or higher?

Comment: I changed the definition to 2.0 and he didnt complained about it, so I think I use 2.0 :)

Comment: I just wanted to know whether for-each-group can be used. Otherwise we would have used Muenchian grouping just like in Martin's solution.
Did you only change the definition or do you have an XSLT 2.0 installed? Usually (with the JDK) you only have 1.0.

Comment: I think 2.0 was preinstalled on this machine. I would be interested to know how a solution with for-each-group would look like, if it's not too much trouble to provide :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming XSLT 1.0 you can group with keys:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:key name="k1" match="violation" use="@priority"/>
<xsl:key name="k2" match="violation" use="concat(@priority, '|', @rule)"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//violation[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k1', @priority)[1])]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="violation">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('prio', @priority, ':&#10;')"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="key('k1', @priority)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k2', concat(@priority, '|', @rule))[1])]" mode="rule"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="violation" mode="rule">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(@rule, ', ', count(key('k2', concat(@priority, '|', @rule))), '&#10;')"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Transforms

```
<files>
<file name="file1">
  <violation rule="rulename1" priority="1">
  </violation>
  <violation rule="rulename2" priority="2">
  </violation>
</file>
<file name="file2">
  <violation rule="rulename2" priority="2">
  </violation>
  <violation rule="rulename3" priority="1">
  </violation>
</file>
</files>
```

into

```
prio1:
rulename1, 1
rulename3, 1
prio2:
rulename2, 2
```